# Understanding a generic flow of a simple data logger via FreeRTOS

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, embedded, freertos

So I came up with this simple flow of the program that could be done without RTOS but I'm using it for the sake of learning.

The generic idea is to get the user input over UART, and if it's something regarding data query, the data query task wakes up, reads the sensor data, wakes up the other task to transfer the data over to RX module.

In other words, I have `ulTaskNotifyTake()` in, say, a Data Task which waits on a notification from a UART task. Upon receiving an input over the UART regarding the query of this data, the UART task would call `xTaskNotifyFromISR()` from the UART's ISR waking up the Data Task, which would query the sensor data...and so on.

Does the generic flow sound OK? I'm still going through a bunch of FreeRTOS docs on APIs but that's a raw image that I thought of. Any suggestions are appreciated.

[image]

Comment: i think that you need to go ahead and try your idea ... come back if you encounter any problems ... it is pointless to be asking your question at this stage because it is an opinion based question, which is not on topic here

Comment: true, but I was trynna get things straight prior to implementing

Comment: @Pokloha What else is your software supposed to do? Because if the only thing you need to do is accept requests for data and respond to them with a reported value, I've no idea why FreeRTOS is involved at all. It's just way, way too simple.

Comment: like I mentioned, I am using rtos for learning purposes; I previously did it before in bare-metal where I was constantly waiting till a meaningful value was inputted and then serviced the request along with sending the data over to a receiver. In what way could rtos be worth using for a similar use case?

Comment: @Pokloha Well, first off you probably don't need an operating system with a focus on "real time" features. In fact, you'd be a lot better off with something quite simple. (It would take me two days, completely from scratch using C and assembly, to write an O/S with threads, inter-task messages, round robin and priority support, and semaphore and sleep queues.) What an O/S buys, and it is worth the trouble often, is simplicity and relative easy maintenance of code. The separate stacks in each thread buy you a lot in that regard and it is worth having.

Comment: @Pokloha Most of what you have in the above is something that is easily handled with a high-side and low-side pair of routines, separated by a receive buffer, to handle the hardware management on one side (the low side driver half) and software abstraction (the high side driver half) on the other side. With that in place (no O/S yet), it's almost trivial to just wait for line and process it in a loop. So no need for an O/S. Where it becomes really nice is when you now have to handle a front panel keypad and display, as well. Then the benefits suddenly spring forward.

Comment: I'm not sure who common is it to write an OS with threads and pretty much everything that FreeRTOS offers from scratch nowadays. I tried to understand the function prior to using them so I know what's happening behind the scenes but I feel if you understand its high level functionality, the low level details shoulnd't bother you.

Comment: Not sure if you're referring to RTOS by software abstraction. Usage of OS is trivial cause you aren't quite making use "shared data" where you could be concerned with things like starving, and data synchronization? Could you elaborate your last point regarding a front panel keyboard & display? Are you referring to displaying the data on a screen? I'm looking for an "excuse" to learn RTOS but obviously in a way I'm learning things & not just for the sake of it. So I shall really appreciate any ideas based on the existing plan...

Comment: @Pokloha Operating systems like FreeRTOS (and this is easily seen with another question you've asked here) require a LOT of study to work out all the features and how to apply them. Also, at times, I work on critical healthcare devices (such as infusion pumps) which require ***every single line of code*** to be fully tested. This means every branch. This isn't possible with outside O/S code. Too complex. Finally, I've been doing O/S since 1975 and I worked on the Unix v6 kernel, as well, in 1978. Since then, many O/S. So it's nothing to me, really.

Comment: @Pokloha I do use appropriate free or commercial O/S when the application requires it, though. Which at times it does. But it takes only an hour or so to create a co-operative switcher in C/asm. And that's often all I need for an embedded application. Most only need at most a couple of days work. I'd spend way more time sussing out someone else's O/S, like FreeRTOS. Not worth it unless the application requires the time (and is willing to pay for it.)

Comment: @Pokloha As far as the application goes, I was just trying to point out a minimum application level of complexity where the features of a basic co-operative (simple, hour's work) or pre-emptive (two days' work) O/S starts to be worth the added effort. Most embedded work is sufficiently complex to warrant the extra time of a couple-three days on the O/S to get sleep, run, semaphore queues operation and to provide separate stacks, pre-emption, thread messages, and priorities and round robin up and going.

Comment: I'm not writing anything from scratch though. FreeRTOS has existing APIs that I am making use of but my main idea is to understand the inner workings through the usage of these APIs be it for task notifications or semaphores...so I can say to someone that I have some sort of exposure to RTOS & put on my resume